# Errors with Angular $http GET and jsonp

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp, etsy

Having a lot of difficulty connecting to Etsy API with both http an jsonp.

URL works fine in the browser: 
https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/GreatLakesModern/listings/active?api_key=5a61qc30hrvrqcperugollh5&fields=title&callback=JSON_CALLBACK

But gives 404 error with jsonp and 0 status error with $http.get

<strike>I don't believe it's an issue of CORS, because when I test other APIs on CodePen, they work. Substitute the Etsy URL and no luck.</strike>

Did some more research and found that Etsy is not CORS-compatible. With that knowledge, how should I proceed?

Example:
http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/YXXQxj?editors=101

I've tried an assortment of solutions, but here is my current code:

```
var url = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/GreatLakesModern/listings/active?api_key=5a61qc30hrvrqcperugollh5&fields=title&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

$http.jsonp(url)               
            .success(function (data) {$scope.details = "Success";})
            .error(function (data, status) {$scope.details = "Nope"+""+status;});
```

Comment: Just because other APIs work, doesn't mean that the Etsy one won't fail because of CORS...

Comment: CORS test showing that if fails: http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=https%3A%2F%2Fopenapi.etsy.com%2Fv2%2Fshops%2FGreatLakesModern%2Flistings%2Factive%3Fapi_key%3D5a61qc30hrvrqcperugollh5%26fields%3Dtitle%26callback%3DJSON_CALLBACK&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote

Comment: @JoseM That's fair enough. I actually just did some more research and found that Etsy is indeed not CORS compatible. With that knowledge, what do I do?

Comment: Here is the working omdbapi test: http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client#?client_method=GET&client_credentials=false&server_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.omdbapi.com%2F%3Ft%3DSherlock%2520Holmes%26tomatoes%3Dtrue%26plot%3Dfull&server_enable=true&server_status=200&server_credentials=false&server_tabs=remote

Comment: you need to call it from your own backend server (or create a proxy server).  Their api may not be meant to consumed from a browser, and you may want to change your api_key now that it is in the public.

Comment: @JoseM Thank you for the links. With Etsy being CORS incompatible, shouldn't a jsonp request still work? https://github.com/TIY-Houston-Front-End-Engineering/Notes-Sept-2014/blob/master/day20.md#jsonp-vs-json

Comment: For jsonp to work, the service itself needs to support it. They need to wrap the response in whatever you provide as the callback.  See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: @JoseM Ah! It finally clicked. That all makes sense. Thanks for the link. I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just looked at the link you posted and it does seem that Etsy supports jsonp.  But you have to change how you call their api.

Instead of https://..../active?api_key=...

You need to do https://..../active.js?api_key=...&callback=etsyResult123

Notice the addition of the `.js` part.

More precisely, with Angular's `$http.jsonp` api it would be

```
var url = "https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/GreatLakesModern/listings/active.js?api_key=5a61qc30hrvrqcperugollh5&fields=title&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
```

Here is a working plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ulaMTo?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, I reviewed the Github link as well and found the same solution. The data can also be selectively requested with `&fields=title,url` (etc.) . Thanks so much for your persistence.